# Plesk is down but the site works fine

Tags: centos, vps

I have a very strange problem on my vps hosting. For some reasons the I can no longer access the plesk control panel. When I open the address in my browser I get the default error message that the this webpage is not available, as if the server is down, but the site itself works normal... I use linux/centos vps hosting, with plesk 10.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not such an unusual occurrence. The Plesk control panel is a bolted-on set of scripts which you interact with through the web server process. The fact that Plesk is unreachable means that there is likely something wrong with whatever http server you are running or with the Plesk scripts themselves (if they've been updated, perhaps).

Here are some tips:

- Check the Plesk error logs: `/usr/local/psa/admin/logs`
- Check your HTTP server's error logs.

  - CentOS Apache error logs: `/var/log/httpd/error_log`
- Reboot your HTTP server
- "Reboot" Plesk

  - `~# /etc/init.d/psa stop`
  - `~# /etc/init.d/psa start`
- Reboot your VPS (although, that's not a *solution* by any means)

That should get you well on your way.

---

Since it appears that the psa file does not exist, you appear to have a serious problem. Check your bash history to see what commands have been run. Perhaps something was done to uninstall Plesk or delete critical files. I hope you have a backup. You may need to re-install Plesk. You now know what specificall is wrong with your installation and can either make another question here on ServerFault that specifically addresses the problem (E.g. "Help, /etc/init.d/psa is missing") or go to the Parallels support forums and ask for help. If you are using a host that has installed Plesk for you then they will be able to help. If you have purchased it yourself then Parallels will be able to help.

Comment: I get this message when trying to stop or start plesk: -bash: /etc/init.d/psa: No such file or directory

Comment: `psa-core` has been deleted from the server. Did you remove `wget` by trying `yum remove wget`?

Comment: •"Reboot" Plesk did the Job for me. thx

Answer (score 0):

1. plesk is using own web server and if it's going down this does not affect websites.
2. are you able to start plesk? /etc/init.d/psa start any problem while issuing this command?